# Won't edit field properly

Tags: python, layers, ogr, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile with one layer. I want to create another layer, copy all the features from this layer to the new one, and then delete the first layer. I should say that the new layer has also one new field, called "Flagged".
This is what I'm doing:

```
for feature in range(maxID_node):
    if nodes_layer.GetFeature(feature) is not None:
        new_feature = nodes_layer.GetFeature(feature)
        new_feature.SetField("Flagged", 0)
        new_layer.CreateFeature(new_feature)
new_layer.SyncToDisk()
nodes_shapefile.DeleteLayer(0)
nodes_shapefile.SyncToDisk()
new_layer = nodes_shapefile.GetLayerByIndex(0)
new_layer.GetFeature(3).SetField("Flagged", 1)
new_layer.SyncToDisk()
```

Unfortunately, my attempt to set the feature(3)'s "Flagged" field to 1, fails. It just remains 0 (which is what I set inside the loop). All my attempts with all other features don't work either. Why isn't SetField setting the field to 1?
The Flagged field was created through this code

```
nodefeatureDefn = nodes_layer.GetLayerDefn()
node_feature = ogr.Feature(nodefeatureDefn)
flagged_field = ogr.FieldDefn()
flagged_field.SetName("Flagged")
flagged_field.SetType(ogr.OFTInteger)
nodes_layer.CreateField(flagged_field)
```